# Special Differential Equation (continued-2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

May you help me out in solving inhomogeneous differential equation looking like[this is radial part of Schrodinger equation]:

$$R^{\prime\prime}+\frac{1}{r}R^{\prime}-\frac{a^{2}}{r^{2}}R+b^{2}R-\frac{c^{2}}{r}\delta(r-\rho)R-d^{2}R=F\exp(ikr)$$

Comment: I added LaTeX formatting; please check whether it is what you meant.

Comment: Is $\delta(r-\rho)$ a dirac delta, or a step function or what?

Comment: It's a dirac delta function.

Comment: Where does $r$ lie?

Comment: r goes like 0<r<infinity.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41985/2451

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let's write the equation in a cleaner way:
$$
R'' + \frac{1}{r}R' +\left(b^2 - d^2 - \tfrac{a^2}{r^2}\right)R = F e^{ikr} + \tfrac{c^2}{r} \delta(r-\rho) R \quad \Longrightarrow
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dr}\left\{r\frac{d R}{dr}\right\} + r \left(b^2 - d^2 - \tfrac{a^2}{r^2}\right)R = r F e^{ikr} + c^2 \delta(r-\rho)R
$$
Now, supposing $F$ is a constant, integrating both sides of the equality
\begin{multline}
\int_{\rho-\epsilon}^{\rho+\epsilon} \frac{d}{dr}\left\{r\frac{d R}{dr}\right\} dr + \int_{\rho-\epsilon}^{\rho+\epsilon} r \left(b^2 - d^2 - \tfrac{a^2}{r^2}\right)R = \\
\int_{\rho-\epsilon}^{\rho+\epsilon}\left\{r F e^{ikr} + c^2 \delta(r-\rho) R\right\}dr. 
\end{multline}
Supposing $R$ continous a.e., the second term on the LHS and the exponential term in the RHS will vanish as $\epsilon \to 0$, leaving
$$
\int_{\rho-\epsilon}^{\rho+\epsilon} \frac{d}{dr}\left\{r\frac{d R}{dr}\right\} dr= c^2 R(\rho),
$$
and then you have the jump comdition
$$
\lim_{r \to \rho^+} \left(r\frac{d R}{dr}\right) - \lim_{r \to \rho^-} \left(r\frac{d R}{dr}\right) = c^2 R(\rho).
$$

Now (where is $r$?), for $0 \le r < \rho$
$$
R'' + \frac{1}{r}R' + \left(b^2 - d^2 - \tfrac{a^2}{r^2}\right)R = F e^{ikr},
$$
and the same equation applies for $\rho < r < \infty$.

**Note: I'm only going to solve the case** $|d| \le |b|$, **and** $\textbf{F = 0}$. The *inhomogeneous case* can be solved the same way using variation of parameters (the case $|b| < |d|$ is analogous).

In this case, assuming that $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then
$$
R(r) = \begin{cases}k_1 J_a\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}r\big), & 0\le r < \rho \\ \\
k_2 J_{a}\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}r\big) + k_3 J_{-a}\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}r\big), & \rho < r < \infty\end{cases}
$$
where $J_{\pm a}$ are the [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of order $\pm a$. To determine the values of $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ you have, for example
\begin{align}
R_0&=k_1 J_a(0)\\
0 &= k_2 J_a\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big) + k_3 J_{-a}\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big) - k_1 J_a\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big)
\end{align}
and
\begin{multline}
\frac{k_1}{\rho} J_a\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big) = \\
k_2 J_a'\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big) + k_3 J_{-a}'\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big) -  k_1 J_a'\big(\sqrt{b^2 - d^2}\rho\big),
\end{multline}
where the first equation is the boundary condition, the second is the continuity condition, and the third is the jump condition.

**Lastly**, I've noted that you haven't included neither the domain nor initial/boundary conditions in any of your questions. This very problematic, as the I/B conds. **are part** of the *differential operator*, and strongly determine the solution.