# Numerical Solution of PDE with Singularity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dirac-delta, singularity

I am trying to solve a PDE in $x$ and $t$, which my equation looks as

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=A(x,t)\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}+B(x,t)\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+C(x,t)P+D(x,t)$$

where $P(x,t)$ represents a probability distribution (I am trying to solve a modified version of Smoluchowski equation). I used **Crank Nicolson Algorithm**, but since my starting point is a Dirac Delta function (estimated with very thin Gaussian/Lorentzian), I am getting a negative value of $P(x,t)$ at some points.

With the doubt that there may be error in my code, I calculated the values by using excel by employing the Euler method and found that the problem lies in the almost-singular Dirac Delta function (estimated with very thin Gaussian/Lorentzian). Is there some method to handle this?

**PLEASE NOTE:**

1. Please do not suggest me to go for analytical solution, since the equation I am working on is not solvable (or rather, has not been solved till now) analytically.
2. I thought of using Fourier transform once, but that would help only if the coefficients are constants, which is not true in my case.
3. I have gone through these links, please do not suggest me any of these answers: [(a)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/solving-a-pde-containing-diracdelta), [(b)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-solution-of-heat-equation-with-dirac-delta-function-initial-condition), [(c)](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-numerically-solve-a-pde-with-delta-function-boundary-condition.757623/), [(d)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251799/how-do-i-solve-a-pde-with-a-dirac-delta-function)

Comment: How do you approximate $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$? I suppose the main reason for negative values are oscillations, if this is true, than you need to use a monotone approximation (e.g., upwind) for this term.

Comment: @VorKir Please provide more details